# Retrieve rows based on first condition and stop retrieve rows untill the second condition meets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a requirement to append rows with a column criteria.For exapmle.

This is table

```
Date         B              C     
02/03/2017     NEW          Client1
03/03/2017     NEW          Client1
04/03/2017     NEW          Client1
05/03/2017     PAID         Clinet1
05/03/2017     CANCELLED    Client1
05/03/2017     NEW          Client2
06/03/2017     PAID         Client3
06/03/2017     CANCELLED    Client4
07/03/2017     PAID         Client4
08/03/2017     PAID         Client1
10/03/2017     NEW          Client5
11/03/2017     PAID         Client5
12/03/2017     NEW          Client1
13/03/2017     PAID         Client1
```

---

My requirement:

This is the required table:

```
Date          Status          C
02/03/2017     NEW          Client1
03/03/2017     NEW          Client1
04/03/2017     NEW          Client1
05/03/2017     PAID         Clinet1
05/03/2017     NEW          Client2
10/03/2017     NEW          Client5
11/03/2017     PAID         Client5
12/03/2017     NEW          Client1
13/03/2017     PAID         Client1
```

I would like to create a dataframe -- Client's  took time to Status = 'NEW' to Status = 'PAID'.

I tried with:

```
enter code here


for index,row in df.iterrows():    
    if row['Status'] == 'NEW':   
        df_new.loc[index] = row 
        df_new.append[which(Status == 'NEW') -1,]
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible example for your dataframe so anyone can help you.

Comment: Thank you Talha.I will give an example when the client added some thing to the shopping cart the status starts as 'NEW' if he took time and add something to the cart then the status is 'New' with a new row with time change.when he pays the status changes to 'PAID'.if not the status remains 'NEW'

Comment: My requirment is that,I would like to make a dataframe of client's  who took time to 'PAY' or  with left over cart.In the dataframe I would also collect the time duration for the client's started with 'NEW'  to 'PAID'